# Android / Java: is there a unique way to identify an Activity even after orientation change without using onSaveInstanceState Bundle?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Android: is there a unique way to identify an Activity even after orientation change without my own custom identifier and without using `onSaveInstanceState` Bundle?

When I print `this.hashCode()` in the `onCreate` method and `finish()` methods, they are the same but when I change the orientation of the device, causing the Activity to be recreated, the `this.hashCode()` value changes. Is there some other way to uniquely identify an Activity which stays the same even after orientation change and re-creation?

Currently I am using the following solutions:

In `onCreate()`:

```
val tempUUID = localClassName + "_" + UUID.randomUUID().toString()
uniqueUUID = savedInstanceState?.getString("uniqueUUID",tempUUID) ?: tempUUID
```

In `onSaveInstanceState`:

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    outState.putString("uniqueUUID",uniqueUUID)
}
```

This works but I am wondering if there's a better way which doesn't require me to use this subclass for every Activity.

Comment: Could you try `intent.hashCode()` once? If it works I will add it as an answer. I am not sure actually.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  After rotation your Activity was stopped, deleted, and a new one was created.  So yeah, its a different instance.  What are you trying to do that requires this?  You're probably missing a better way of doing it.

Comment: `better way which doesn't require me to use this subclass for every Activity` - u can use base Activity which will implements this logic (others will extends base)